# Keep Android Preferences From "Remembering" State

Tags: android, preferences, preference, preferencefragment

I'm using a PreferenceFragment to provide a clear, consistent layout to my users. However, for this particular screen, I need the information to always be clear/fresh/blank/reset each time it's visited.

**For example**:
The user enters some text on the EditTextPreference (let's say "mText") in my PreferenceFragment xml view. When the user exits the screen and comes back to the same PreferenceFragment, I need *NOT* for "mText" to show up in the EditTextPreference when they click it. Currently, it *is* showing up. Or say the user checks a CheckBoxPreference. When they come back, it needs to be unchecked again (the default value/state).

I understand that I *could* manually set the values in code to what I want them to be (i.e. blank/reset). However, this seems tedious and not like the correct way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fragment's onPause() method you can do:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mEditTextPreference.getEditor().clear().apply();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? The documentations says it will clear *all* values from the preferences. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear%28%29

Comment: Whoops, totally misread `getEditor().clear`. I suppose you're right. :)

Comment: You can also use SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
and then prefs.edit().clear().apply();

Comment: Yep, I figured. Thanks a lot! Your answer is exactly what I was looking for.